# How can I set a default value for an optional parameter of a function in typescript?

Tags: typescript

My function in typescript has an optional boolean parameter b.

```
function foo(a: number, b?: boolean){

   ...

}
```

How can I define a default value for the parameter b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default value in the function definition like that:

```
function foo(a: number, b: boolean = true) {

    ...

}
```

Like that the parameter is still optional. But it has a default value in case no value is passed.